# How do we enaable JTA transaction using Spring Java Configuration

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jta, spring-transactions, distributed-transactions, spring-java-config

I am using jta transaction in my application.

I could enable jta using spring-configuration.xml file with tag `<tx:jta-transaction-manager />`

We have `@EnableTransactionManagement` to enable single DB transactions but as we are using `distributed XA transaction` through JTA, need to find out a way to annotate.

How do we create the same using Spring Java `@Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do not do this via the Configuration class itself, rather you annotate the actual class that is going to be transactional (or individual methods).  An example from the Spring documentation:

```
// the service class that we want to make transactional
@Transactional
public class DefaultFooService implements FooService {

  Foo getFoo(String fooName);

  Foo getFoo(String fooName, String barName);

  void insertFoo(Foo foo);

  void updateFoo(Foo foo);
}
```

Comment: @Transactional is the use of Transaction. I wanted to know how to enable/define JTA transaction through annotation in Configuration class. Is there any property available?